# Is it possible to use xlDialogSendMail to send a selected range as PDF?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use xlDialogSendMail to send an email of a selected range as PDF but so far all it is doing is to send it as a workbook.

This is the original code:

```
Sub createSendPDF()

    Dim selectedRange As Range
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim fileName As String
    
    fileName = InputBox("Please enter the name for this file", "PDF Name")
    
    Set selectedRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:H29")
    folderPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp_PDF\" & fileName
    
    selectedRange.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, folderPath, 
    xlQualityStandard, True, False, , , False
    
    
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendMail).Show

End Sub
```

==========================

Problem resolved - Solutiom

```
Sub createSendPDF()
    
        Dim selectedRange As Range
        Dim folderPath As String
        Dim fileName As String
        
        fileName = InputBox("Please enter the name for this file", "PDF Name")
        
        Set selectedRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:H29")
        folderPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp_PDF\" & fileName

        With objMail

              .subject = subject
              .Attachments.Add folderPath & ".pdf"
              .display

        End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: `xlDialogSendMail` is the object model method for "save & send as attachment" - I believe that's always going to be a worksheet format.

Comment: Your selected range should be exported as pdf, but there is not any connection between the pdf created file and the attached one, which all the time will be the active workbook.  Do you have Outlook installed? You should automate it to send the created file as attachment. Or use ADO...

Comment: Yes, I do have Outlook. How can I add the PDF file created as an attachment? I have seem some codes tutorial online but they seem to go over the board. The xlDialogSendMail would be perfect if there is a way to attach the PDF file

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns, I did look the question in the link and it seems what I need. Only problem is that I'm getting an error: Run-time error '440': The operation failed.I have update the code above.

Comment: I found out the problem. on line  `.Attachments.Add = folderPath` needed to be changed to `.Attachments.Add folderPath & ".pdf" ` Thanks for the tip @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns